# Did I convert this pseudo code correctly?

Tags: java, loops, methods, parameters

I just want to make sure that the code I have written below is correctly translated before I submit my work. The method does work, but I feel like I may have written something wrong.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
assign i the value 0

WHILE i is less than the length of the array minus 1

let bubbleI be the bubble at index i in the bubbles array

assign j the value i + 1

WHILE bubbleI is not popped AND j is less than the length of the bubbles 
array

let bubbleJ be the bubble at index j in the bubbles array
IF bubbleJ is not popped AND bubbleI is touching bubbleJ
pop both bubbleI and bubbleJ

END IF

increment j by 1

END WHILE

increment i by 1

END WHILE
```

**My Code:**

```
private void popAll() {

    int i = 0;

    while (i < bubbles.length - 1){

       bubbles[i] = bubbles[i];
       int j = i + 1;

        while (bubbles[i].isPopped() == false && j < bubbles.length){

            bubbles[j] = bubbles[j];

            if (bubbles[j].isPopped() == false && bubbles[i].isTouching(bubbles[j]) == true){

                bubbles[i].pop();
                bubbles[j].pop();             
            }
            j++;          
       }           
       i++;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that "let bubbleI be the bubble at index i in the bubbles array" should become `Bubble bubbleI = bubbles[i];`, rather than that assignment which doesn't actually do anything.

It's also unusual to compare to `true` and `false` in if statements - `foo == true` is exactly the same as `foo`, and `foo == false` is exactly the same as `!foo`.

Finally, the while loops with initialization and increments are exactly what the `for` statement is for, so I'd write the whole thing like this:

```
private void popAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length - 1; i++) {
       Bubble bubbleI = bubbles[i];

       for (int j = i + 1; !bubbleI.isPopped() && j < bubbles.length; j++) {
            Bubble bubbleJ = bubbles[j];

            if (!bubbleJ.isPopped() && bubbleI.isTouching(bubbleJ)) {
                bubbleI.pop();
                bubbleJ.pop();             
            }
        }           
    } 
}
```

Or, you can keep the while loops.. It's unclear if it's expected that you literally translate the pseudo-code, or that you try to write idiomatic code instead..